# Kubernetes: remove label - unknown shorthand flag: 'c' in -color

Tags: kubernetes

I've created a label with:

`kubectl label pods <pod id> color=green`

but removing it using:

`kubectl label pods bar -color`

gives:

`unknown shorthand flag: 'c' in -color`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The dash goes at the end of the label name to remove it, per `kubectl help label`:

```
# Update pod 'foo' by removing a label named 'bar' if it exists.
# Does not require the --overwrite flag.
kubectl label pods foo bar-
```

So try `kubectl label pods bar color-`.